# validating java inputs for mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb

I have created a registration form which works fine adding a users details to MongoDB. The problem I'm having is validating a username and password in the login form. The details are entered in the registration form as follows:

```
MongoCollection<org.bson.Document> collection = db.getCollection("Members");

        Document doc = new Document("firstname", jTxtFirstName.getText())
           .append("surname", jTxtSurname.getText())
           .append("username", jTxtUsername.getText())
           .append("password", jTxtPassword.getText())
           .append("phone", jTxtPhone.getText())
           .append("email", jTxtemail.getText());
           collection.insertOne(doc);
```

I'm assuming that the username and password would be validated through a read query. I'm unsure how to perform this. Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write code (or use some library) to validate and sanitize the user input. You can for example use regular expressions.

```
String username= jTxtUsername.getText()

// write code to validate username
```

Comment: Appreciate the reply. I understand how to validate for example, that all text entered in the username is in string format or that the phone number is in digit form. I would like to be able to check that the username and password are correct credentials for login matching pre-existing members credentials in the database???

Comment: @hongkongtom in that case you need to query your database, to check if the username and password match the ones stored. You have to do this check before insert the object into the collection.

Comment: query the data before I insert it into the database?? I'm a bit confused on that

Comment: where do you have the usernames and password stored? this, how do you know they are correct?

Comment: I'm using MongoLabs database-as-a-service for storing the data. They are stored in a 'Members' collection in a database called 'bidchaser'. The members are adding correctly. I need to query the data in a login form using the username and password fields from above